# I want to know how to get the selected data on another webpage using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have use loop to show limited data and each loop i have button to select it.

I have a syntax error in my view.php i dont know what to put in that query
How do i select a row in index.php to view more details in view.php. I tried giving it a name in the echo $rows; loop but i got syntax error too.

This is my code in index.php

```
<?php
    $sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT fname FROM info");

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqlQuery)){
            echo $rows['fname'];
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Show more info' name='submit' class='btn btn-info'>"; 
    }
?>
```

-----------------------end code for index------------------------------
this is my code in view

```
<?php
    $sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE fname=$_POST['fname']");
    echo "<table border='1' width='50%'>";
    echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>First Name</td>";
            echo "<td>last Name</td>";
            echo "<td>Age Name</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqlQuery)){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $rows['fname'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $rows['lname'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
                echo $rows['age'];
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

-------------------------------end code for view--------------------

Comment: What is your syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="POST" action="view.php">
<?php
    $sqlQuery = mysql_query("SELECT fname FROM info");

    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sqlQuery)){
            echo "<input type='text' value='".$rows['fname']."' name='fname'>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Show more info' name='submit' class='btn btn-info'>"; 
    }
?>
</form>
```

Try this in view.php

```
echo $_POST['fname'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE fname LIKE ".$_POST['fname']."";
echo $query;
```

check what output are you getting

Comment: is this right for view.php sqlQuery? $viewQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE fname LIKE".$_POST['fname']."");

Comment: @NathanNathaniel `$viewQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM info WHERE fname LIKE ".$_POST['fname']."");` missing space after `LIKE`

Comment: Does ".$_POST['fname']." is correct? cause i got this error mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\CandR\view.php on line 23

Comment: i got this result meResource id #5

Comment: Now im getting two result instead of the one i've only click.